# Embedding Ember/Angular apps into pre-existing site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js, javascript-framework

I've built small apps in Angular and Ember and have enjoyed working with both-- the structure and functionality of using these frameworks have made coding up the UI a blast!

I was wondering whether there was a way to embed these apps into a pre-existing legacy site? For Angular, I know you can define a target div as your ng-app. Is there a better way of doing this? What about Ember? Are there any issues I need to look out for with regards to compatibility/integration?

I realize these frameworks are primarily meant for SPAs but like I said, I really like the opinionated nature and long-term maintainability benefits of using them.

I tried looking online but I haven't found resources regarding this topic (maybe for good reason). Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

For ember, the proper way is to insert into an existing div.  You can declare the div to insert into when defining your ember app as such:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#divName'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For AngularJS you only need to specify where you want the angular part of the code to be compiled.
By adding:

```
<div ng-app='MyApplication'></div>
```

you include the app that you will then import at the end of the index.html file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='myApplication.js'></script>
```

Then in your application you can create your app and follow the AngularJS module structure from that point on.

```
var application = angular.module('myApplication', []);
```

Comment: This works as well and you do not need to add an ng-app attribute: angular.bootstrap($("#yourElement"), ["modulename"]);